# laravel foreign key to current table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the following table structure which allows users to submit a comment, or a reply to a comment:

```
Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->integer('model_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('parent_comment_id')->unsigned();
            $table->text('comment');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('set null');
            $table->foreign('model_id')->references('id')->on('models')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('parent_comment_id')->references('id')->on('comments')->onDelete('cascade');

        });
```

I have a foreign key `parent_comment_id` which points back to the `comments` table. This is to show that the comment (while still being a comment object) belongs to a parent comment.

How does one go about defining this relationship within the model for the comments table (/App/Comment.php)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try something like this (In `App\Comment` model):

```
public function replies()
{
    return $this->childComments()->with('replies');
}

public function childComments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class, 'parent_comment_id', 'id');
}
```

So, you may use `Comment::with('replies')` to load all the related replies recursively. You may become confused because of two functions used for the relationship and this because one reply may contain it's own replies so you need a resursive relationship. So, `replies()` will load all the replies with it's own replies. You may also check [this post of mine](http://heera.it/laravel-model-relationship#.Vv6Xo5x97IU) that I've written a couple of years ago for `Laravel - 4` but the idea is same.

```
// Another example could be something like this
$post = Post::with('comments.replies')->find(1); // Get Post with all comments with replies
```

---

**Note:** In this case, the `Post` model must contain a `comments()` (hasMany) relationship method.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Comment extends Model
{
    public function parentComment()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Comment');
    }
}
```

You can see more info in [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships) doc page.